# SystemParametersInfo parameter definitions for C#

Tags: c#, include, system-calls, definitions

I want to make a call to SystemParametersInfo from C#. The first argument to this function is one of a large collection of possible values like SPI_GETACCESSTIMEOUT, which are listed in the documentation, but don't seem to be defined anywhere.

I can go find the actual values of these things on the web, and make up an enum with the right magic numbers in it - that works, but it's not the right thing. I want to be able to include something that does all that for me. They have to be defined somewhere!

What do I do to make this work properly?

---

OJ points to the [SPI page](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/SPI.html) which is great if I want to copy all that into my source code.
But I want the compiler to do that.

I should just be able to say:

```
[DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, bool uParam, int lpvParam, int fuWinIni);
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETACCESSTIMEOUT, 0, ref IsActive, 0);
```

Instead I need to add:

```
public const uint SPI_GETACCESSTIMEOUT = 0x003C;
```

... and all the rest of it as well. I'm looking for some command that will import all those definitions from wherever they live in the dll.

Comment: So what you're essentially asking for is a managed version of SystemParametersInfo. The short answer is, there isn't one (at the time of posting). You have to use p/invoke as demonstrated already. That's just the way it is!

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what pinvoke.net is all about :)

See the [SystemParametersInfo page](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SystemParametersInfo.html) for a full description and sample code. Bear in mind you have to use pinvoke to deal with this API as far as I'm aware.

Cheers!

**EDIT:** In case it's not immediately obvious, the information for SPI_GETACCESSTIMEOUT can be found on the [SPI page](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/SPI.html) (which is linked from the SystemParametersInfo page). There is also another sample [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/844cc956-3da0-4c27-b61e-6f9818db9d38).